# Not able to retrieve urdu/arabic data from SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using an Oracle database 11.2.0.4 with AL32UTF8 CHARACTER SET, I have data stored in urdu/arabic language in my database, I can query my data from the db server (linux) but I am not able to select/view the data from SQL Developer  Version 4.0.0.13, is there any specific setting we need to perform in order to display data from SQL Developer?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pick a display font that supports your characters.

[image]

Comment: Hi, by changing the font, font is changing in the worksheet but in output it is still the same.

Comment: Could be a bug, you are on a VERY old copy of SQL Developer - i'm using version 18.4, you're on version 4.0.3

Answer (score 0):

Open `Tools > Preference > Environment` and change `Encoding` to `UTF-8`

Like this picture:

[image: image1]

Answer (score 0):

First export by setting Encoding to UTF-8

Open then resultant sql file in notepad++. In notepad++ select the Encoding as Encode to UTF-8.